# Pasar api_token a archivo JS

Tags: javascript, json, laravel-5

estoy trabajando con una api que envia datos de los usuarios registrados en la base de datos a una vista y tengo un archivo js que los lee del json, pero quiero que el api_token sea dinamico, ya que cada vez que se registra un usuario se crea uno para cada registro, es decir que cada usuario use su token, tengo la ruta en mi archivo routes/api.php definida de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function(){

    Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('users', function(){
    return App\Empleado::all();
});
});
```

Esta extrae los datos de la tabla empleado y los envia como Json mediante la ruta /api/v1/users, despues el archivo list-datatable.js los recolecta:

```
"use strict";
// Class definition

var KTUserListDatatable = function() {

    // variables
    var datatable;

    // init
    var init = function() {
        datatable = $('#kt_apps_user_list_datatable').KTDatatable({
            // datasource definition
            data: {
                type: 'remote',
                source: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/api/v1/users?api_token=aERxFplzawvyg17SBElZWkyOZzBCnxRLeY8iqBZaipm78f0YkUkgxL5iVgel',
                    },
                },
                pageSize: 10, // display 20 records per page
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true,
            },
```

hasta aqui todo bien, el detalle radica en que el middleware se autentica mediante el api_token, como pasaria este valor al archivo js mediante una variable para que sea mas dinamico?

Comment: Podrías añadir una cookie y luego llamarla en el fichero.